# Wait for table creation when executing mvn install from batch file

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, batch-file, jpa

I have a **batch** file that locally :

1. create a **Maven** project from an archetype
2. create the related **MySQL** database
3. install the project (so **JPA/Hibernate** creates the tables)
4. populate the tables using an **SQL file** (`INSERT` statements)

The (simplified) batch file :

```
[...]

echo ====== CREATE MAVEN PROJECT =======
call mvn -X archetype:generate ...

echo ====== CREATE DATABASE ============
mysql -u%mysql_local_user% -p%mysql_local_password% -e "create database %dbName%"

echo ====== INSTALL PROJECT ============
call mvn clean install -Pmyconfig -DskipTests=true

set /P ISDBREADY=Please make sure the table creation completed before continuing, is it OK (Y/N)?
if /I "%ISDBREADY%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

echo ====== POPULATE DATABASE ==========
mysql -h localhost -u%mysql_local_user% -p%mysql_local_password% --default-character-set=latin1 %dbName% < ../init_database.sql

:END
```

As you see, for the moment I just prompt a message so I can check that the tables are there, then I can continue and populate the database.
If I don't wait, the tables don't exist yet when the `INSERT` statements are executed and I get an exception (*Unknown table name ...*).

Is there any way I can just know when the tables are ready and can be populated? Then I can get rid of the prompt or any wait instructions.

Comment: JPA provides a property that will execute an SQL script when you start up the `EntityManagerFactory`. Why not just use that?

Comment: I need to execute it only once, not every time I run `mvn install`. Also my batch takes as parameter the name of the application, then before calling the SQL script it updates the file to replace some data according to the parameter value (but OK it should not be a problem as I can also do it before running `mvn install`). I admit that I have heard about that JPA solution but it is highly under-documented, and thought I had read that the script is executed before table creation. I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: "Highly under-documented" ? It seems to have ample documentation for the JPA provider I use http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/persistence.html#schema-generation  Set the relevant property and it performs what the property suggests it should do

Comment: You're right but I'm not looking for a documentation that just tell me the property to use, I expect it to explain the details (when is the script executed? can we supply several files? where the file should be located? is there any way to execute that script only once? what occurs if the script is executed several times? etc.). For example, I use the hibernate implementation, should I use `javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source`, `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source` or `javax.persistence.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`? They all seem to work fine, it's pretty unclear.